# Using binary from remote server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, webserver, remote

If I upload `nc or`curl` bins to the root of my web server, can I run commands remotely using (GET|POST) requests?

```
http://website.com/nc -lv 1234
http://website.com/curl http://foo.com -o bar.txt
http://website.com/curl%20http%3A%2F%2Ffoo.com%2F%20-o%20bar.txt
```

The above examples don't seem to work. Can someone offer a verbose answer and enlighten me?

Comment: I don't really see a question in there. Are you asking how to execute an arbitrary command supplied remotely from an unauthenticated connection? Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, no you can't. The "problem" is that `nc` and `curl` aren't made to execute in response to GET or POST requests. The binary is sitting on your web server, waiting to be invoked by someone on that same server. Not because of any request your server receives.

Could you make it work? You could, but it's a pretty big security issue so I wouldn't.

If you aren't concerned about the security of your web server, you could create a page called `exec.php` containing:

```
<?php echo shell_exec('curl localhost');?>
```

If you want true remote code execution (please don't do this) you could use:

```
<?php echo shell_exec($_GET['cmd']);?>
```

Then invoke the command with a GET to http://webserver/exec.php?cmd=id

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would it only be possible with PHP? How about running shell scripts remotely?

Comment: JavaServer Pages could enable a similar functionality, though I don't think it's the solution you're looking for.
If you want to use shell scripts remotely, why don't you use ssh?
`ssh user@hostname command`

Comment: Well, I'm working on a cybersecurity CTF (it's pretty obvious I'm trying to do something nefarious on a server :p) and we only have ftp/sftp access. The *ftp service doesn't allow ssh. I thought if I PUT a binary in the root we could pivot or escalate somehow. There's no way to execute a binary via ftp, right? | edit: oh, we can't run php scripts on the site/server either

Comment: Ahh there's the missing context. If you have FTP access, I'd check for some kind of directory traversal. Maybe you can read more directories on the file system.
If you're lucky, you'll have access to upload stuff to the web root. If that's the case, you'll need to learn a little bit more about the web server itself. Msfvenom can help you generate reverse shells in Java, for example.